# Database connectivity with sulu-minimal

Tags: sulu

I have created new project and download from here https://github.com/sulu/sulu-minimal, but i don't know in which file has database configuration option.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running already Sulu 2.0 (develop branch) or Sulu 1.6 (master branch)?

In 2.0 it is in the [.env file](https://github.com/sulu/sulu-minimal/blob/develop/.env#L33), and it can be configurate as described in the [Symfony Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#configuring-the-database).

In 1.6 there is a file at `app/config/parameters.yml`, which is copied from the [`app/config/parameters.yml.dist` file](https://github.com/sulu/sulu-minimal/blob/master/app/config/parameters.yml.dist#L2). There the database can be configured with all the parameters starting with `database_`.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I Got it.
In sulu 1.6, I know how to configure database.
But in Sulu 2.0, I don't know how to configure database?

Comment: they should allow commenting with < 50 reputation. Also, this is not a question?